# post request not working in play scala appication

Tags: scala, playframework

I am creating simple application in scala and play framework, when I use post request it is not working and it gives me "Unauthorized" , you must be authenticated to access this page,

Though I am not using any authentication yet why I am getting this error ?

on Get I am seeing login page, but after filling up form and then using post I am not able to redirect to home page

Comment: Can you post the actual error message? Also what version of Play?

Comment: This is probably due to CSRF filter, check out the following:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaCsrf

Comment: @RobertUdah play version is 2.5.15 and  Error messge: Unauthorized

You must be authenticated to access this page.

Comment: Yes it might just be the CSRF filter setting than will need to be configured.

Answer (score 1):

As I stated in comment author is probably missing CSRF token:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaCsrf, I linked docs for play 2.6 because they tell more about usage of CSRF headers in views (which should also work in previous versions).

It may also be possible that application is accessed at wrong address, check out the following: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/AllowedHostsFilter.